# Python translate a cpickle generated file to text file

Tags: python, arrays, pickle

I saved a 4d array into binary code by using cpickle. Now I want to read it in C language. How can I change the format of that file to `.txt` or any readable file in C?

Comment: A Python program that reads the pickle file and uses the struct module to write a binary file readable by the c program may be the easiest option.

Comment: The *only* purpose of pickle is to be a simple way to store python objects on disk so that other *python programs using pickle* can retrieve them. It looks like you simply *do not* want to pickle your data, you want to convert it to an other format. So simple use `pickle.load` to re-obtain the python object and do convert it into the textual representation you need.